# VS Database Project keeps skipping a table

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, visual-studio-2019, database-project

I have a Visual Studio (2019) Database Project that skips generating a table no matter what I do, and I cannot figure out why.

**Background:**

I created the project by importing from a SQL database up in Azure that had an existing table structure.  The database was pretty much a prototype and I was pulling it in to speed up creating the "real" database.

I then modified pretty much all of the tables in the project, applying some standard naming conventions, indexes, etc.  I added seed data files as part of the Post Deployment, etc.

Then to prep for a test of clean install of the database and the test data, I drop everything in the SQL Server database.

**What I tried:**

First I attempted to publish the database project to my newly empty database.  I "Generate Script", execute the script (from VS) only to discover that it is trying to add an index to a table that doesn't exist.  I swear the Item table is there...and sure enough it is in the Project.  It is set to build too.  But looking at the deploy script, it does not have the Item table.

**What I tried next:**

Fast forward to my next attempt, ignoring hours of VS updates, build, rebuild, clean, restarts, etc.  I move on the doing a schema compare from my project to the empty database, knowing that it will generate all of my create statements but not include my post-deploy files.  (I decide I can hand-run them later).  Compare against an empty database looks like one would expect (nothing but whitespace on the right side of the schema compare screen).  I generate the update script and look at the "Preview" (excerpt below) and my Item table is there:

```
** Highlights
     Tables that will be rebuilt
       None
     Clustered indexes that will be dropped
       None
     Clustered indexes that will be created
       None
     Possible data issues
       None

** User actions
     Create
       [db_executor] (Role)
       [dbo].[ApiKey] (Table)
       [dbo].[AppLog] (Table)
       [dbo].[AppLog].[IX_AppLog_SessionId] (Index)
       [dbo].[Customer] (Table)
       [dbo].[Customer].[IX_Customer_ExternalId] (Index)
       [dbo].[Customer].[IX_Customer_OrganizationId] (Index)
       [dbo].[Customer].[UX_Customer_Name] (Index)
       [dbo].[CustomerDepartment] (Table)
       [dbo].[CustomerDepartment].[IX_CustomerDepartment_DepartmentId] (Index)
       [dbo].[CustomerSetting] (Table)
       [dbo].[CustomerSetting].[IX_CustomerSetting_SettingId] (Index)
       [dbo].[Department] (Table)
       [dbo].[Department].[IX_Department_ExternalId] (Index)
       [dbo].[Department].[UX_Department_Code] (Index)
       [dbo].[ImageResource] (Table)
       [dbo].[Item] (Table)
       [dbo].[Item].[IX_Item_UPC] (Index)
       <snip>
```

Next I look at the SQL script generated and find that my Item table is omitted again, with the index on Item coming right after the ImageResource table create:

```
PRINT N'Creating [dbo].[ImageResource]...';


GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ImageResource] (
    [ImageResourceId] INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [URL]             NVARCHAR (2048) NULL,
    [ContentType]     NVARCHAR (128)  NOT NULL,
    [Width]           INT             NULL,
    [Height]          INT             NULL,
    [IsActive]        BIT             NOT NULL,
    [Created]         DATETIME2 (7)   NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy]       NVARCHAR (128)  NOT NULL,
    [Modified]        DATETIME2 (7)   NULL,
    [ModifiedBy]      NVARCHAR (128)  NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ImageResource] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ImageResourceId] ASC)
);


GO
PRINT N'Creating [dbo].[Item].[IX_Item_UPC]...';


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Item_UPC]
    ON [dbo].[Item]([UPC] ASC);
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT1:**

To add some additional information, I do see in the output script that there are a few ALTERS that point to my "skipped" tables.  So VS clearly thinks that the table exists in the destination DB.  Since it doesn't, I speculate that the destination database metadata must be stored / cached somewhere and that it is out of date.  I have deleted the obj and bin folders.  Anyone know if/where this cached destination DB metadata could be?

**EDIT2:**

So confusingly, if I click "Publish" instead of "Generate Script" to magically deploy the database the publish actually works, creating all of the tables.  But what is extra weird is the `ProjectName.publish.sql` that gets generated as part of the publish is just like the one that gets created is you select "Generate Script" in that it is **missing** 5 out of the 25 tables.  So the SQL commands that are run under-the-covers during the Publish is **not** the same as the `ProjectName.publish.sql` that is output.

Unfortunately, I need the publish SQL file to give to the DBA to run "for real", I can only do a direct VS deploy to my dev database.

Comment: Change table name from [Item] to [Item2].  Verify existence of column attributes within table Item template.

Comment: That was interesting, I used Reafctor -> Rename and then Publish and reviewed the script, and the Item2 was there.  I renamed it back and Item was then present.  I tried executing and the same issue has arisen on another table.  I will keep repeating this process I guess.

Comment: Eerie.  Might just Rename/Rename each one and be done with it?  Or wait until they come up one by one?

Comment: The magic has stopped.  Same issue with Order.  Renamed to Order2 but it is left out of the generated publish SQL script.  This is the weirdest thing I have hit in a long time and I've spent so many hours on it!  Any idea where VS keeps the information about the tables in the destination DB, maybe it is cached?  Or is it fetched fresh on each Publish to create the deployment script?

Comment: Lets see if I've got this right.  Started from Azure-prototype pulled into VS-Proj-DB.  Then modify VS-Proj-DB (lots) and ADD VS-Proj-seed-files. Prep by drop everything in Sqlserver-DB. Finally VS-Proj-DB schema compare to (now empty) Sqlserver-DB ==> generate all Create stmts. ERGO, xyz table is missing from VS-Proj-DB?? Source is VS-Proj-DB, so look there.  Not at destination Sqlserver-DB. (or update my understanding of the sequence...).

Comment: But the Order.sql file does exist in the project, and is set to Build.  Further, many other entities point to Order via Foreign Key such that if it was missing the project wouldn't compile.  Additional info, I made an edit earlier today to add that I found ALTER instead of CREATE for Order and a few other entities.  So as stated in the edit, it feels like VS thinks the table exists.  Does VS cache the destination table info somewhere so I can clear or refresh it?

Comment: @tcarvin Educated guess: First, I would try to remove the content of `ProjectName.refactorlog` and perform a clean publish. Second thing to check: adding explicit filegroup to table `CREATE TABLE dbo.Item(...) ON [filegroup_name];`

Comment: Deleted refactor log, obj, bin, localdb but it did not fix the issue.  This is an Azure SQL database so filegroups are not used.

Comment: Added some addition info in edit 2.

Comment: check file properties and make sure build option is set properly

Comment: Build Action is set to "Build"